# Problem of probability

Tags: probability, means

I got this problem:

It is required to select a person from n. To do this, each person spear
a coin and it is agreed that if one obtains a different result
from the others, then that person is the selected one; otherwise
coins are thrown again under the same conditions. Determine
the expected number of games made until a person is selected.

I tried to define a random variable which tells us the number of games that it takes to select the n-th person Tn, so Tn has a distribution Geometrically with parameter 1/2. So the mean is:

E(Tn) = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1/2)^{n} = \frac{1}{1/2} \ = 2$

Am I right?

Comment: No.  $n$ is a constant; don't use it as an index for a series.  You have $n$ coins, each thrown at the same time.  You want to know the expected count for times thrown until only one coin shows a different face than the other $n-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guide:

First compute the probability of exactly one person get a different outcome. That is either everyone but one person get heads or everyone but one person get tails.

$$\binom{n}{1}\frac1{2^n}+\binom{n}{n-1}\frac1{2^n}=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$$

Now, apply this probability value to  a geometric distribution.